# Are No Interface View (@LocalBean) EJB beans initialized at server startup

Tags: java-ee-6, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1

I am using Glassfish server. It seems that the `@LocalBean` is getting initialized at server startup. For other beans they are correctly initialized on look up. Is this the correct behaviour for LocalBean ?

Comment: Just as a reminder: an LocalBean gives you the same view that you get if the bean doesn't implement any business interface and also *does not* have LocalBean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no rule saying that `@LocalBean` should be eagerly initialized and others should not. It's left to the container provider to decide **when** particular bean should be initialized.

The only case you have control over when bean is initialized is to use `@Singleton` EJB with `@Startup` annotation. This will force container provider to create an instance of the singleton bean during server startup. This is a good place to put your initialization logic within.

The behavior you've observed might be correct in case of Glassfish but I would not relay on it because other container providers might choose different approach.

Comment: Yes my bad. When the EJB server is first started, it may create a number of stateless bean instances and enter them into the Method-Ready Pool.

Comment: Exactly. And the `@LocalBean` is no special kind of EJB - it's just a special kind of view, so it doesn't change the semantics of EJB.